# How to check whether monero-wallet-rpc is running?

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc

I installed monero-wallet-gui on mac. I can't run curl commands to [Wallet RPC](https://web.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#get_payments) because it needs digest authentication. How do I check if monero-wallet-rpc is running so I can configure it(input my user/password).

Comment: What command line (parameters) are you using when starting `monero-wallet-rpc`?

Comment: And curl supports digest auth ( `--digest`).

Answer (score 1):

If you know the port monero-wallet-rpc listens on, you can connect to that port to see whether something is listening. This is what the python RPC layer does.

From utils/python-rpc/console.py in the Monero tree:

```
  # check for open port
  s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  s.settimeout(1)
  if s.connect_ex((host, port)) != 0:
    raise Exception('No wallet or daemon RPC on port ' + str(port))
  s.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could run `ps aux | grep monero-wallet-rpc` to see if the process is running.